How many TAG tags we need in meta?
I was searching tags for my meta question and it feels tags and tagging both are applicable but do we even need to have them separately ?
Also tag-synonyms and interesting-tags can be made synonym of it too.

We could probably merge tags and tagging here, which would simplify things, even though you could argue there are some minor differences (nouns versus verbs, etc.).
I disagree that tag-synonyms (valid) and "interesting-tags" should be merged either into that or together, they are different things - we seem to be using the tags and tagging to discuss use of a particular tag, whilst tag-synonyms should be specifically for requests to combine tags.
I think I've burnt "interesting-tags".

Sound pretty fine to me.
